# Personalizing Gitlab CE

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, ubuntu-18.04, gitlab-ce

I've installed Gitlab CE on my Ubuntu 18.04 operating system and want to customize it's interface and change it based on the Scrum methodology. Is there any way I can change Gitlab user interface and personalize it?
You can assume that I want to translate its UI!

I installed the Gitlab in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-gitlab-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: Change it in what way?

Comment: That's my question :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only UI customization you can have can be found on `/profile/preferences` or `/admin/appearance`.

If you want to customize the appearance, it is up to you to fork Gitlab CE, edit whatever you want, and then maintain it if you want to change the deployed version.

Answer (score 0):

It's open source so you can customize it in any way you want. Here's [introductory documentation about translation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/i18n/), which links to [docs about the code you'd need to change](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/i18n/externalization.html).

If you let us know what specific customizations you want to make we can give you more specific answers.